# AJAX success call not firing on success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I cannot seem to get my Ajax success function to work when I submit my ajax post. Any reason you can see why this might be happening? The failure doesn't fire either so something isn't working correctly. It's a little voting system that I'm trying to make, so on upvote it submits a POST and on Downvote it submits a POST.

```
 $('.up').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var cardId = JSON.stringify({ cardId: id });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/upvote",
        data: cardId,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(resp){
            console.log(resp)
        },
        failure: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
});

$('.down').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var cardId = JSON.stringify({ cardId: id });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/downvote",
        data: cardId,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(resp){
            console.log(resp);
        },
        failure: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are the requests being posted at all? You can check in your browser's _Network_ console. Also, what are the `.up` and `.down` elements?

Comment: @Phil it seems as though they are `Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/upvote
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Comment: FYI, the `failure` callback property should be `error`

Comment: @Phil yeah I was messing around with it, it's fixed now.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. It should be `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.error(textStatus, errorThrown) }`. It always pays to refer to the documentation when you start running in to problems ~ http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Phil when I changed that I got an error `parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Ut (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)`

Comment: Well, there you go. Your response `Content-type` is `application/json` but the body is not valid JSON. This is not a client-side problem

Comment: @Phil is it a database error? Or a server error most likely in your opinion?

Comment: I cannot possibly know. Start by looking at the actual response in your _Network_ console and work back to the server from there. The content of this question is no longer applicable to the problem.